# Parse push fails to load notification icon first time

Tags: android, parse-platform

This is a bit of a weird one. I'm using Parse.com (v1.4.1) on Android, with push notifications via GCM. Whenever I install my app through Gradle, the first push notification fails to load the correct icon. According to their logging, the drawable is not valid:

> D/com.parse.ParseNotificationManager( 3974): Icon id 2130837517 is not a valid drawable. Trying to fall back to default app icon.

There is no such problem with subsequent push messages, making for an irksome situation:

[image: Screencap showing three push icons, one of them wrong]

My app is open source, the full project is [on GitHub](https://github.com/jeroenleenarts/sebastiaanschool). The icon is `ic_push_ntf.png` in the various res/drawable directories. The way I register for the push messages is in [SebApp.java](https://github.com/jeroenleenarts/sebastiaanschool/blob/master/Android/Sebastiaanschool/src/main/java/nl/sebastiaanschool/contact/app/SebApp.java):

```java
final ParseInstallation currentInstallation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
currentInstallation.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
  @Override public void done(ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class, R.drawable.ic_push_ntf);
        PushService.subscribe(getApplicationContext(), "bulletin-android", MainActivity.class, R.drawable.ic_push_ntf);
        PushService.subscribe(getApplicationContext(), "newsletter-android", MainActivity.class, R.drawable.ic_push_ntf);
      }
    }
});
```

The default push callback is there for forward compatibility purposes, all my current pushes are sent through one of the two channels. My pushes are few and far enough between that people probably won't really notice, but this icon thing bothers me and I want it fixed.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: I have the same problem now. The icon is wrong for the first time. Could you find any solutions to this?

Comment: by the way i just used the latest version of sdk(1.5.0) and it didn't happen again. you can try too. https://parse.com/docs/downloads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question to confirm that the 1.5 version of the Parse SDK made the problem go away.